# Result of character(0) when I try to scrape data from marketchameleon.com

Tags: r, rvest

I was wondering if someone can help me, I'm trying to scrape all the publicly available quarterly earnings of Apple Inc on the site marketchameleon.com via rvest package, as of now there are 4 quarters.

You can see the highlighted part the one that I need to get:
[image]

```
url <- "https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/AAPL/Earnings/EPS-Results/"
page <- read_html(url)
name <- page %>% html_nodes('.symov_currsym') %>% html_text()
name
```

the output is a character(0)

I tried also with the selector gadget finding the xpath

```
url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath="//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "rightcelltd", " " )) and (((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 6) and parent::*)]")
```

but the same result, help would be much appreciated!